# How to solve interpolation with polar coordinates at 0 degree (0º/360º)?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, heatmap, polar-coordinates

I'm working in a project at LabMiM/UFBA, with an equipment called 'Fly Eye Sensors', with total 17 sensors distributed in a semi-sphere, pointing to the top. With that said, the standard way of output of the data is:

```
list_example = [[10,45,23,65,12,43,34,23],
                [54,76,23,54,98,12,43,49],
                [12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12]]
```

Since there is only one sensor at the top, I replicate 8 same values of this sensor, resulting in a 3x8 array.

In the code below, I distributed the coordinates of each value in "matriz_original" at "coordenadas" for a 30x100 array, so I could interpolate the values, as you can see in the lines of code below:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

# Defining the matrix, cited above (3x8)
matriz_original = gerar_valores(labmim_backup, 0)

# Definindo as coordenadas dos valores na nova matriz
coordenadas = np.array([[[28,11],[28,22],[28,33],[28,44],[28,55],[28,66],[28,77],[28,88]], 
                        [[25,11],[25,22],[25,33],[25,44],[25,55],[25,66],[25,77],[25,88]], 
                        [[7,11],[7,22],[7,33],[7,44],[7,55],[7,66],[7,77],[7,88]]])

# Definindo a grade da nova matriz
x_new = np.linspace(0, 99, 100)
y_new = np.linspace(0, 29, 30)

# Criando uma função interpoladora
f = interp2d(coordenadas[:, :, 1], coordenadas[:, :, 0], matriz_original, kind='cubic')

# Aplicando a função interpoladora na nova grade
nova_matriz = f(x_new, y_new)
```

Then, I plot these values with "contourf" function with polar projection , distributing the angle from 0 to 2π in 100 parts, and the range from the center in 30 parts, matching the sizes of the interpolated matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import pandas as pd

#fake data:
a = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100) # Sepação das partes em radianos
b = np.linspace(0,1,30) # Camadas por distancia ao centro
A, B = np.meshgrid(a, b)
c = nova_matriz

orig_map=plt.cm.get_cmap('hot')

#actual plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=120,subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ctf = ax.contourf(a, b, c, cmap=orig_map.reversed())
plt.colorbar(ctf)
```

[Heatmap for Solar Radiation in Polar Projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZmbi.png)

The main problem is: **How can I fix the anomaly at zero degree?**

I want to make a smoother shading between values at the extremes of the matrix, fixing the sudden changes at this part of the plot.

I've tried a lot of things, took some help from ChatGPT but no solutions came out.

I've tried a lot of things, took some help from ChatGPT but no solutions came out.

First, they gave me a new function "RegularGridInterpolator". The problem with it is that I can't put values without being at the top or the bottom of the matrix, resulting in a strange plot, with "hidden" values that I want to show which are at the extreme top and bottom. Furthermore, it continues with the same issue at the zero degree:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the original matrix
original_matrix = gerar_valores(labmim_backup, 0)

# Define the coordinates of the values in the original matrix
r = np.linspace(0, 1, 3)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 8)
R, Theta = np.meshgrid(r, theta)
x = R * np.cos(Theta)
y = R * np.sin(Theta)

# Define the coordinates of the values in the interpolated matrix
new_r = np.linspace(0, 1, 30)
new_theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
new_Theta, new_R = np.meshgrid(new_theta, new_r)
new_x = new_R * np.cos(new_Theta)
new_y = new_R * np.sin(new_Theta)

# Create a two-dimensional interpolation function
interp_func = RegularGridInterpolator((r, theta), original_matrix)

# Apply the interpolation function to the new coordinates
new_matrix = interp_func((new_R, new_Theta))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(dpi=120,subplot_kw=dict(projection='polar'))
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ctf = ax.contourf(new_Theta,np.flip(new_R,0), new_matrix, cmap=orig_map.reversed())
plt.colorbar(ctf)
```

[Heatmap for Solar Radiation in Polar Projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdAvi.png)

Comment: Convert your angles to 2d complex coordinates, do a 2d interpolation.  Unfortunately getting rid of these sort of "gimbal lock"-esque problems is usually not straightforward, and requires adding a degree of freedom to the system.